# Signal low delay for specific amount of time / hardware - equivalent of Arduino pulseIn() function

Tags: circuit-design, timer, optoelectronics

I have a circuit similar to the following:

[image: schematic diagram]

(Source: [electronicsforu.com - Shadow Alarm: Light Sensitive Circuit](https://electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/hardware-diy/light-sensitive-alarm-circuit))

In the circuit, the output from op-amp pin 6 goes low when a shadow falls or light is not present.

I am using this to find out if an obstacle is present or not and it can be done only this way, according to our constraints. The obstacle blocks the light and so the voltage from pin 6 goes low. These are moving obstacles with a certain width, so the light is blocked until the width passes and this width is constant. However we have smaller obstacles in the same line which we should ignore, based on the width.

In simpler terms, if the light is blocked (voltage is low) for only for 20 millseconds, then we have to ignore it. However if the light is blocked (voltage is low) for more than 40 milliseconds, then it is a valid obstacle. I have to do it only with hardware, not using functions similar to Arduino pulseIn() etc.

Comment: So you want a circuit that recognizes when a pulse is wider than 40ms but always ignores pulses narrower than 20ms? Is that the essence of your question?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  yes , a circuit that recognizes when the pulse is wider than a certain time and ignores if it is lower than that time

Comment: No. you can't pick just one "certain time". There must be a minimum duration that is always ignored and a maximum duration that is always recognized, and the greater you make the difference between those two the easier it will be to solve your problem.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ok understood , how can i achieve that

Comment: How close together are the potential objects? For example can you get a 20ms with 10ms spacing to a 40ms object.

Comment: @JackCreasey these objects are pretty far from each other actually these are joints on a fabric that block the light to pass through , so can be 100 mts apart and i can choose the width of the joint to block, but on the fabric itself some tiny elements that can block the light which is a false trigger

Comment: **You** must specify the minimum and maximum duration values before someone can tell you how to do it.

Comment: You simply need to find a just-under 40ms timeout timer with appropriate input and output polarity.  Every time a pulse starts it runs.  If the pulse is short it gets reset before it can complete.  But if the pulse is long, it has time to complete and generate an output before being reset again by the end of the input pulse.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Unfortunately, it's not that simple. You need logic to generate the output pulse from two timers. So conceptually possible (you could use two 555 timers) but much more complicated when you add together with the interface from the sensor. I'm not sure you will end up being very simple. Draw the schematic, if it does the job I'd certainly upvote it.

Comment: No, read the description again, you only need a single timer, which is either allowed to complete and generate output, or reset before it can.  The functional description is already provided in words, all that remains is selecting the best part to fulfill the function.  Conceptually you could do it with a capacitor charged through a resistor but discharged directly, and a comparator to see if/when it hits a desired threshold...

Comment: @ChrisStratton If it's so simple then prop up the schematic. I'm certainly interested in your approach. The idea with the capacitor is intriguing, how will you stop it producing very narrow pulses that could be missed. At least in my solution you get a definite minimum pulse width out, which I viewed as essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one trigger point to be defined, you don't need upper and lower boundaries defined.
For your application any signal 40ms and longer creates an output and less than 40ms creates no output.

The circuit below is just an example of what you might do using conventional logic:

[image]

The logic is as follows:

1. U1A provides a high or low signal to the shift register on its inputs A, B. If the photo transistor in illuminated, then the input to the shift register is low.
2. U1B provides a clear signal to the shift register (U2) when powered up and sets all the shift register outputs to zero.
3. With all the outputs zero the *Output of U3 is high.
4. U4 is a 200Hz oscillator. (this could be a 555 astable if you like) The oscillator clocks  the value of the A, B shift register inputs through the Q outputs.
5. For any high (inputs A, B) input values below 40ms there will always be at least one zero bit in the shift register, so the *Output will always be high. If the input signal extends beyond 40ms then for at least one clock period the *Output will be low.

While this logic should work (I have neither simulated or built this), the task would be much better accomplished using a small single chip MCU.

Comment: I guess c1 acts as  tank capacitor, i didn't get the purpose of d1

Comment: C1 provides a power on delay on startup. D1 rapidly discharges C1 when the power is turned off. Any solution is built using standard 'blocks' of logic ….not sure what you expected.

Comment: This is an **absurdly** overcomplicated way to address a very simple problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you think so ….then let's see your attempt NOT using an MCU. Put your knowledge where you mouth is.

Comment: All they need is a 40 ms timeout timer with appropriate input/output sense, it gets reset before it can complete if the pulse is short, when the pulse is long it gets to run to completion and generate output

Comment: @ChrisStratton So show this simple circuit. If it's so easy, you'll help the OP no end. I'm certainly interested to see this simple solution.

Comment: what are some alternatives for l14f1 phototransistor for improved sensitivity for intensity of light , if my  supply voltage limit is 24V

Comment: datasheet for l14f1 https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/L14F1,%20L14F2.pdf